# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function'; fatal error LNK1120: 1 Unresolved external

Tags: c++

Hi I made a simple C++ program and I'm getting errors and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to C++ syntax so I can't figure out what mistake I made that is causing the stated linker errors. Here is sample code that generates this error:

ITest.h

```
#ifndef ITest_H
#define ITest_H

//#[ ignore
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// disable Microsoft compiler warning (debug information truncated)
#pragma warning(disable: 4786)
#endif
//#]

//## auto_generated
#include <string>
//## auto_generated
#include <algorithm>
//## auto_generated
//## link itsNmNeighborhoodEntry
class NmNeighborhoodEntry;
//## class ITest
class ITest {
//#[ ignore

    ////    Constructors and destructors    ////

public :

    //## auto_generated
    virtual ~ITest();

    ////    Relations and components    ////

protected :

    NmNeighborhoodEntry* itsNmNeighborhoodEntry;        //## link itsNmNeighborhoodEntry
};

#endif
```

ITest.cpp

```
//## auto_generated
#include "ITest.h"
//## link itsNmNeighborhoodEntry
#include "NmNeighborhoodEntry.h"

//## class ITest
ITest::~ITest() {
}
```

Test1.h

```
#ifndef Test1_H
#define Test1_H

//#[ ignore
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// disable Microsoft compiler warning (debug information truncated)
#pragma warning(disable: 4786)
#endif
//#]

//## auto_generated
#include <string>
//## auto_generated
#include <algorithm>
//## class Test1
#include "ITest.h"
//## auto_generated
class NmNeighborhoodEntry;

//## class Test1
class Test1 : public ITest {
//#[ ignore

    // Default Constructor is Private
    public:
       Test1();


    // Default Copy Constructor is Private
    private:
       Test1(const Test1& self);


    // Default Assignment Operator is Private
    private:
       Test1& operator=(const Test1& aTest1);
//#]

    ////    Constructors and destructors    ////

public :

    //## auto_generated
    ~Test1();

    NmNeighborhoodEntry* getNmNeighborhoodEntry();
};

#endif
```

Test1.cpp

```
//## auto_generated
#include "Test1.h"
//## auto_generated
#include "NmNeighborhoodEntry.h"

NmNeighborhoodEntry* itsNmNeighborhoodEntry;

//## class Test1
Test1::~Test1() {
}

Test1::Test1() {
}


NmNeighborhoodEntry* getNmNeighborhoodEntry() { 
    //return itsNmNeighborhoodEntry;
    return NULL;
}
```

NmNeighborhoodEntry.h

```
#ifndef NmNeighborhoodEntry_H
#define NmNeighborhoodEntry_H

//#[ ignore
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// disable Microsoft compiler warning (debug information truncated)
#pragma warning(disable: 4786)
#endif
//#]

//## auto_generated
#include <string>
//## auto_generated
#include <algorithm>

//## class NmNeighborhoodEntry

class NmNeighborhoodEntry {
//#[ ignore

    // Default Constructor is Private
    private:
       NmNeighborhoodEntry();


    // Default Copy Constructor is Private
    private:
       NmNeighborhoodEntry(const NmNeighborhoodEntry& self);


    // Default Assignment Operator is Private
    private:
       NmNeighborhoodEntry& operator=(const NmNeighborhoodEntry& aNmNeighborhoodEntry);
//#]

    ////    Constructors and destructors    ////

public :

    //## auto_generated
    ~NmNeighborhoodEntry();

    bool myIsPending;       //## attribute myIsPending

    unsigned short index;       //## attribute myNodeIndex
};

#endif
```

NmNeighborhoodEntry.cpp

```
//## auto_generated
#include "NmNeighborhoodEntry.h"

//## class NmNeighborhoodEntry
NmNeighborhoodEntry::~NmNeighborhoodEntry() {
}
```

driver.cpp

```
//#include "ITest.h"
#include "Test1.h"
//#include "Test2.h"
#include "NmNeighborhoodEntry.h"

Test1 *test1;
//Test2 *test2;
NmNeighborhoodEntry* myNmNeighborhoodEntry;

void main() {
    test1 = new Test1;
    //test2 = new Test2;

    //test1->itsNmNeighborhoodEntry = NULL;
    myNmNeighborhoodEntry = test1->getNmNeighborhoodEntry();

}
```

Comment: In general, that means you declared something and used it but never defined it.  However, I don't think that you're really getting the exact error that you say you're getting.

Comment: You show 3 headers declaring classes with member functions. You only show one file implementing (some) members. Where are the rest? The linker doesn't find them.

Comment: Bo Presson, I just added the missing files. Please help if you can. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're getting means that the referenced 'symbol' is not defined. It also tells you in which 'function' the reference to 'symbol' is made.

You are probably missing a function or method implementation somewhere.

Edited:

```
NmNeighborhoodEntry* getNmNeighborhoodEntry() { 
    //return itsNmNeighborhoodEntry;
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is your error; it needs to have the class name qualifying it like this.

```
NmNeighborhoodEntry* Test1::getNmNeighborhoodEntry() { 
    //return itsNmNeighborhoodEntry;
    return NULL;
}
```

The way you are doing it declares a global function. You need to have Test1:: before the name of the function to indicate to the compiler that this is the implementation of a method of the class Test1.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to obfuscate your error message like that.

Comment: It complains that Test1::getNmNeighborhoodEntry() is not defined, but it clearly is in the Test1.cpp.  Have you tried compiling the code?

Comment: It should. I have tried compiling this code and it generates the error.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I would not have noticed that.